# find the relevant files with their checksum

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, find, hashsum

We want to find all the .jar files with their chksum.

```
find . -name "*.jar"

./lib/ant-1.8.0.jar
./lib/ant-launcher-1.8.0.jar
./lib/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
./lib/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar
./lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar
./lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
./lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
./lib/jline-0.9.94.jar
```

expected output

```
find . -name "*.jar"

ant-1.8.0.jar  325235345 4564
ant-launcher-1.8.0.jar 3523535 5453
.
.
.
```

Is it possible to add to find the command with sum, and print all .jar files with the relevant sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the exec action of `find` to do this:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec cksum {} \+
```

The `exec` action runs the `cksum` command on each result of `find`. The `+` operator specifies that multiple results from `find` are passed to a single execution of `cksum`.

Do note that the order of columns is slightly different from your question. This is governed by the output of the `cksum` command, which outputs the information as [checksum] [byte count] [filename].